# Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'

Tags: c#

```
using System;

class Eggs
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter amount of eggs: ");
        string numberEggs = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Amount of eggs are: ", + numberEggs);
    }
}
```

The start of my code. There's much more to add to it but yeah, first I need to get past this obstacle which the console is throwing out for me in VS Code. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it a lot.

**error CS0023: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'**

I have no idea how to fix this. I try to push it for an int instead of a string, then I get this:

**error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'**

Comment: `"Amount of eggs are: ", + numberEggs)`  Remove the comma.  It's trying to use the unary plus operator, which doesn't work on strings, because of the typo.

Comment: Much appreciated... I feel like an idiot after the last comment from Amy. Sorry, literally started with C# a week ago at uni.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simply typo. Your `Console.WriteLine` should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("Amount of eggs are: " + numberEggs);
```

In other words, no comma.

A more up-to-date way of doing this is:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Amount of eggs are: {numberEggs}");
```